# Unable to update newly linked issue - Jira/Scriptrunner - Epic/Issues In Epic

Tags: groovy, jira, tempo

I have a piece of code. I am able to view all the values, but when it comes to updating the newly linked issue's Tempo "Account" field, nothing happens. I am using  Scriptrunner For Jira's custom listener

I would expect the newly linked issue (issueInEpic) to have it's Tempo "Account" field (linkedField) value (oldCfValue) updated with the value (newCfValue) of the Epic's "Account" field value.

log.info() shows all of the values properly. The only issue is updating the linked issue.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.link.IssueLinkDeletedEvent
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexingService
import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.IssueChangeHolder


def log = Logger.getLogger(com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.link.IssueLinkCreatedEvent)
log.setLevel(Level.INFO)


if ([IssueLinkCreatedEvent].contains(event.getClass())) {


    if (event.issueLink.issueLinkType.name == "Epic-Story Link") {
          def currentUser = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext.loggedInUser 
          def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
          def cfManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
          def accountField = cfManager.getCustomFieldObjects(event.issueLink.sourceObject)?.find{it.name == "Account"}
          def linkedField = cfManager.getCustomFieldObjects(event.issueLink.destinationObject)?.find{it.name == "Account"}
          MutableIssue issueInEpic = event.issueLink.destinationObject as MutableIssue
          MutableIssue epic = event.issueLink.sourceObject as MutableIssue
          def newCfValue = accountField.getValue(epic) 
          def oldCfValue = linkedField.getValue(issueInEpic)


          issueInEpic.setCustomFieldValue(linkedField, newCfValue)
          issueManager.updateIssue(currentUser, issueInEpic, EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH, false)


        def issueIndexingService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueIndexingService.class)
        def wasIndexing = ImportUtils.isIndexIssues()
        ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(true)
        issueIndexingService.reIndex(event.issueLink.destinationObject)
        ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(wasIndexing)

        log.info(accountField)
        log.info(newCfValue)
        log.info(oldCfValue)
        log.info(issueInEpic)
        log.info(epic)
        log.info(linkedField)
        } 
}
```

Comment: Are currentUser have permission to update issueInEpic?

Comment: Yes. While running the tests I am doing so as admin. But, I've been scrouging about and found out I will need to implement REST in order to modify a TEMPO field.*I am currently learning how to do this*